# .htaccess If file exists, set document root to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, document-root, apache-modules

I would like to use .htaccess to set a rule where if config.php exists then set root directory to / and if config.php does not exist, set root directory to /install.

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/config.php !-f
RewriteRule ^/?$ /install [L]
```

This will set /install as your home dir if /config.php does not exist in your filesystem.